# Foreach only outputs last item

Tags: loops, foreach, fwrite

I'm trying to use a foreach to save the results to a file but it only writes the last result of the array.

```
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');
$myFile = "urls.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");

$html = file_get_html('the-url');

foreach($html->find('a.bnone') as $element) 

    $stringData = $element->href . '\n';
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        //echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

The commented echo works and displays all the results, the fwrite only writes the last one to the file. What is the problem?

Comment: What's the HTML code? maybe 'a.bnone' only selects the last element, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place curly braces around your `for each` because you have two statements in there but only the first is being looped in the foreach, the last element is thus put in `$stringData` and the `fwrite` function is only called once.

```
foreach($html->find('a.bnone') as $element) {

    $stringData = $element->href . '\n';
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    //echo $element->href . '<br>';
}
```